# Locked my screen with xtrlock on a Live Disk and now can't unlock

Tags: apt, data-recovery, lock-screen, data-loss

I'm running Photorec data recovery on a 2TB external disk using an Ubuntu LiveUSB, and wanted some way of locking the screen and protecting it from feline sabotage while still being able to see what's on the screen.

I searched online and came across [xtrlock](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/xtrlock.1x.html). I installed it with `sudo apt-get`, and then ran `sudo xtrlock` assuming this would bring up some configuration options like I'm used to on Windows. Instead, it immediately locked my screen, and because I'm running a LiveDisc, which has no users or passwords, I'm now unable to unlock it.

**Is there any way at all that I can unlock my machine without restarting it and/or interrupting the data recovery operation?**

Comment: "protecting it from feline sabotage" LMAO !!!

Comment: I upvoted just for the "feline sabotage" thing. :P On a more serious note, what file system was the external drive using? It seems you are coming from Windows... was it NTFS?

Comment: It was registering as FAT16, but that was probably due to having its partitions messed up by the partial format I accidentally run on it. I'm not positive but it was more than likely NTFS.

Comment: Also, I didn't have time to wait to figure this out, and had to shut the laptop down and interrupt the data recovery, but this is still worth an answer for anyone who comes across the problem in the future. As for me, I restarted the data recovery program, and it's still vulnerable to my cat, but I prefer that over being locked out of it again. Someday I'll have the luxury of figuring out how to get a transparent screen lock working. Today is not that day. Today I just keep a close eye on the cat.

Comment: Why would you use Photorec on NTFS? You can recover filenames and partitioned files with other tools. Also, please mention me in replies otherwise I don't see the notification. :)